# Is there any way for a program reading from a FIFO to detect that a program writing to the same FIFO has closed it?

Tags: c, linux, fifo, epoll

Using epoll in C, is there any way for a program reading from a FIFO to detect that a program writing to the same FIFO has closed it?

I thought that this would generate an EPOLLHUP event, yet apparently it doesn't.

Example:
I have a reader and a writer. The writer makes and opens three FIFOs and writes some floats to them and closes them when done. The readers open the FIFOs and monitor them, print out the floats as they come, and should close the FIFOs when the writer closes them (by checking for the EPOLLHUP event). This doesn't work and the reader just stays in an infinite loop until terminated. Code below, as well as logs from my reader and writer.

Reader code:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define POLL_TIMEOUT 1000 * 5

struct fifo
{
    char *path;
    FILE *fp;
    int fd;
    struct epoll_event ev;
};

#define dbg_fmt(str, ...) {\
    time_t curr_time = time(NULL);\
    struct tm *curr_tm = gmtime(&curr_time);\
    fprintf(stderr, "[%d:%d:%d] "str"\n", curr_tm->tm_hour, curr_tm->tm_min, curr_tm->tm_sec, __VA_ARGS__);\
}

#define dbg(str) {\
    time_t curr_time = time(NULL);\
    struct tm *curr_tm = gmtime(&curr_time);\
    fprintf(stderr, "[%d:%d:%d] %s\n", curr_tm->tm_hour, curr_tm->tm_min, curr_tm->tm_sec, str);\
}

int main(void)
{
    int num_fifos = 3;
    int num_active_fifos = num_fifos;

    struct fifo *fifos = malloc(sizeof(struct fifo) * num_fifos);

    int epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
    struct epoll_event *epollev = calloc(num_fifos, sizeof(struct epoll_event));

    for(int i=0; i<num_fifos; i++)
    {
        fifos[i].path = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen("fifoX"));
        sprintf(fifos[i].path, "fifo%d", i);

        dbg_fmt("opening %s", fifos[i].path);
        fifos[i].fp = fopen(fifos[i].path, "r+");
        fifos[i].fd = fileno(fifos[i].fp);

        fifos[i].ev.data.ptr = (void *)&(fifos[i]);
        fifos[i].ev.events = EPOLLIN;

        dbg_fmt("registering %s with epoll", fifos[i].path);
        epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fifos[i].fd, &(fifos[i].ev));     
    }

    dbg("entering poll loop");

    while(num_active_fifos > 0)
    {
        dbg("waiting for event...");
        int num_events = epoll_wait(epollfd, epollev, num_fifos, POLL_TIMEOUT);\

        for(int i=0; i<num_events; i++)
        {
            struct fifo *curr_fifo = epollev[i].data.ptr;
            dbg_fmt("recieved event from %s", curr_fifo->path);

            if(epollev[i].events & EPOLLIN)
            {
                float fl;
                fscanf(curr_fifo->fp, "%f", &fl);
                dbg_fmt("read %f from %s", fl, curr_fifo->path);
            }

            if(epollev[i].events & (EPOLLHUP|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLERR)) {
                dbg_fmt("closing %s", curr_fifo->path);
                epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL,curr_fifo->fd, NULL);
                fclose(curr_fifo->fp);
                num_active_fifos--;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<num_fifos; i++) {
        free(fifos[i].path);
    }

    close(epollfd);
    free(epollev);

    free(fifos);

    dbg("done");
    return 0;
}
```

Writer code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>


#define dbg_fmt(str, ...) {\
    time_t curr_time = time(NULL);\
    struct tm *curr_tm = gmtime(&curr_time);\
    fprintf(stderr, "[%d:%d:%d] "str"\n", curr_tm->tm_hour, curr_tm->tm_min, curr_tm->tm_sec, __VA_ARGS__);\
}

#define dbg(str) {\
    time_t curr_time = time(NULL);\
    struct tm *curr_tm = gmtime(&curr_time);\
    fprintf(stderr, "[%d:%d:%d] %s\n", curr_tm->tm_hour, curr_tm->tm_min, curr_tm->tm_sec, str);\
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    mkfifo("fifo0",0755);
    mkfifo("fifo1",0755);
    mkfifo("fifo2",0755);

    int fifo0 = open("fifo0",O_WRONLY);
    int fifo1 = open("fifo1",O_WRONLY);
    int fifo2 = open("fifo2",O_WRONLY);

    dbg("made FIFOs, sleeping for 5s");
    sleep(5);

    dbg("writing one value to each fifo (1.2, 0.5, -1.3)");

    write(fifo0, "1.2 ", strlen("1.2 "));
    write(fifo1, "0.5 ", strlen("0.5 "));
    write(fifo2, "-1.3 ", strlen("-1.3 "));

    dbg("sleeping for 5s");
    sleep(5);

    dbg("closing fifo2");
    close(fifo2);

    dbg("sleeping for 5s");
    sleep(5);

    dbg("writing two remaining values (-1.0 and 3.2) to fifo1 & closing it");

    write(fifo1, "-1.0 ", strlen("-1.0 "));
    write(fifo1, "3.2 ", strlen("3.2 "));
    close(fifo1);

    dbg("sleeping for 5s");
    sleep(5);

    dbg("server: writing remaining value (-2.5) to fifo0 & closing it");

    write(fifo0, "-2.5 ", strlen("-2.5 "));
    close(fifo0);

    dbg("done");
}
```

Reader log:

```
[18:42:3] opening fifo0
[18:42:3] registering fifo0 with epoll
[18:42:3] opening fifo1
[18:42:3] registering fifo1 with epoll
[18:42:3] opening fifo2
[18:42:3] registering fifo2 with epoll
[18:42:3] entering poll loop
[18:42:3] waiting for event...
[18:42:8] waiting for event...
[18:42:11] recieved event from fifo0
[18:42:11] read 1.200000 from fifo0
[18:42:11] waiting for event...
[18:42:11] recieved event from fifo1
[18:42:11] read 0.500000 from fifo1
[18:42:11] recieved event from fifo2
[18:42:11] read -1.300000 from fifo2
[18:42:11] waiting for event...
[18:42:16] waiting for event...
[18:42:21] recieved event from fifo1
[18:42:21] read -1.000000 from fifo1
[18:42:21] waiting for event...
[18:42:26] recieved event from fifo0
[18:42:26] read -2.500000 from fifo0
[18:42:26] waiting for event...
[18:42:31] waiting for event...
[18:42:36] waiting for event...
[18:42:41] waiting for event...
^C
```

Writer log:

```
[18:42:6] made FIFOs, sleeping for 5s
[18:42:11] writing one value to each fifo (1.2, 0.5, -1.3)
[18:42:11] sleeping for 5s
[18:42:16] closing fifo2
[18:42:16] sleeping for 5s
[18:42:21] writing two remaining values (-1.0 and 3.2) to fifo1 & closing it
[18:42:21] sleeping for 5s
[18:42:26] server: writing remaining value (-2.5) to fifo0 & closing it
[18:42:26] done
```

Comment: How did you `open` the FIFO? Please show some code, as [MCVE]. And your question is OS specific (perhaps lacking a *Linux* tag). Read also about `SIGPIPE` on [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Of course, you need first to have consumed (on the reader side) all the bytes kept in the FIFO. See [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) & [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

Comment: I've added a code example with which I'm having trouble as well as the Linux tag. Thanks.

Comment: If all the processes that had a FIFO open for write have exited, then the reader process will get EOF (0 bytes read) from a read call.  The file descriptor becomes 'readable without blocking' as it will return EOF immediately.

Comment: Note that once the reader process gets 0 bytes because there are no writers, it will continue to get 0 bytes until there is a writer again, and it may do a form of busy waiting while waiting for a writer to appear.  One way to avoid that problem is to close the FIFO and reopen it.  The open blocks until there is a writer, eliminating the busy waiting and delays caused by sleeping between attempts to read if that's what you do to alleviate the busy waiting.  So, it is usually sensible to close the file descriptor after getting EOF, and then reopen and continue again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reader needs to `fopen` the FIFO with mode `r`, because `r+` is reading **and** writing. So, when the writer closes all FIFOs, there is still the reader, that has write access and the EPOLLHUP signal will not be generated.