# Read multiple times in a single named pipe

Tags: c, process, pipe

I got a school project and been searching for hours on how to prevent my program to terminate when it reads one "message" through pipe.

The goal is to have a 'server' waiting for requests from clients, and obviously clients that can send requests to this server.

I have 2 executables 1 for server, and 1 for clients (that can be executed multiple times if you want multiple requests at the same time)

Notice that when the server receives a request, it must creates a process (fork) that will do the necessary job, meanwhile the main process can still receive more requests

Everything works absolutely fine when I do a request, the problem is that it terminates the server execution, and I have no clue on how to prevent it.

Here is the code that receives the request from client from **pipe**, I removed a lot a things that are used for the calculations I got to do but it doesn't affect my problem
**server.c :**

```
    if(read(**pipe**,buffer,REQUEST_LENGTH) != REQUEST_LENGTH){
      perror("read");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pid_t worker = fork();
    if(worker == -1){
      perror("fork");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
      //SOME UNINTERESTING THINGS
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

On termination of server.c, perror says "Read : Success"

Comment: *""Read : Success"* indicates *errno* was not set during the read, meaning `read` is returning a value less than `REQUEST_LENGTH` (short reads are perfectly valid; you must repeatedly call `read` until you have read the *expected* number of bytes). There are not enough details here to provide you with much more information than this. Please post a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problematic program(s).

Comment: To emphasize: calling `read` outside of a loop is almost always a bug, and this isn't an exception.

Comment: _Pipe_ reads _can_ return a _short_ length. So, comparing the length against `REQUEST_LENGTH` won't work. You want: `ssize_t rlen = read(mypipe,buffer,REQUEST_LENGTH);` Then, just use `rlen` as the number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If, at any time after a reader has opened a FIFO successfully (meaning that there was a writer at that time), there are no writers left on the FIFO, then the reader gets EOF each time it reads from the FIFO (which can easily end up as a busy loop).  If the reader closes the FIFO after receiving EOF and reopens it, it will hang in the open using no resources until another process opens the FIFO for writing.

There is some code available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `fifo-*-41.[ch]` in the [src/so-4825-2451](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-4825-2451) sub-directory.  The code was prepared as an answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48252451/15168), but there was a simpler solution to that particular problem that someone else provided, so I never posted the code explicitly.

There are two programs:

- `fifo-rdr-41` which reads data from a FIFO.
- `fifo-wrt-41` which writes data to a FIFO.

You could run the reader in one terminal window and the writer in a second terminal window.  If you simply run `fifo-rdr-41`, it will continue to try reading after getting an EOF, but there is a random delay of 250-750 ms between attempts.  If you run `fifo-rdr-41 -r`, then it will reopen the FIFO after receiving EOF.  If you run `fifo-rdr-41 -w`, then it will also open the FIFO for writing (and `fifo-rdr-41 -r -w` is legitimate too).

In the second terminal, run `fifo-wrt-41` repeatedly to send data to the FIFO.  You could arrange to run multiple copies in parallel if you wanted too.  There are no controls; it writes a random number of blocks of random upper-case letters, with a 250-750 ms random delay between writes and another random delay before closing the FIFO.

#### Example 1 — Reader keeps FIFO open after receiving EOF

Terminal 1: `fifo-rdr-41`

```
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:43:18.965 - pid=71914: Creating FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:43:18.966 - pid=71914: Open FIFO './test-fifo' for reading
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.330 - pid=71914: FIFO './test-fifo' opened for reading
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.330 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.915 - pid=71914: 893 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.915 - pid=71914: Data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
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.915 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.309 - pid=71914: 496 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.309 - pid=71914: Data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
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.309 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.935 - pid=71914: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.935 - pid=71914: Napping 0.557 seconds
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:15.495 - pid=71914: Woke up 0.557 seconds later
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:15.495 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:15.495 - pid=71914: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:15.495 - pid=71914: Napping 0.499 seconds
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:15.996 - pid=71914: Woke up 0.499 seconds later
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:15.996 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:15.996 - pid=71914: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:15.996 - pid=71914: Napping 0.323 seconds
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:16.323 - pid=71914: Woke up 0.323 seconds later
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:16.323 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:16.323 - pid=71914: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:16.323 - pid=71914: Napping 0.408 seconds
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:16.734 - pid=71914: Woke up 0.408 seconds later
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:16.734 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:16.734 - pid=71914: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:16.734 - pid=71914: Napping 0.680 seconds
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:17.416 - pid=71914: Woke up 0.680 seconds later
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:17.416 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:17.416 - pid=71914: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:17.416 - pid=71914: Napping 0.522 seconds
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:17.941 - pid=71914: Woke up 0.522 seconds later
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:17.941 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:17.941 - pid=71914: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:17.941 - pid=71914: Napping 0.294 seconds
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.235 - pid=71914: Woke up 0.294 seconds later
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.235 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.524 - pid=71914: 351 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.524 - pid=71914: Data: [OORFJGIYUKOWERSICRKHRQRSRDOYRWDLBQCGPPUPFMUTEDHLAJINRWUBYDCFLTDGIAXNPPDQDRCQPVZLEGNJSONSJUTXYEAQDMUXDYFKBUQDNWFCJNXGSLCJVJOCPCHKOERUOJAJUINWTBYOYVAKFOMJPBDCSCMDNVKKRRPJUJKCTCGVGGHIUXVXGAKQFCKVQIUXRNDMUEARVZWRXNOOLYPJHYCBVBMMJEDBKSLGEQFHXVZAUTCMDUFWWHKZNJWVBUCJDJJPWIFMWONIRVPQFTTVZWMVNXCLJOWUFZKUACZAPBJXAEGRJARZALSLWLEXUFEPMNIUTFISQUZNEXKLVCNZNUGVMWM]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.524 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.023 - pid=71914: 465 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.023 - pid=71914: Data: [DYZJOTBGVECGSGBNYNTCVPUSTQGIQQSYTMXWZOQLBUQMGFPILPRIRGTOZFKNHERVCXLFDPLDOKRUCNPNTMCKJXLBGHRIBHKUEKLUGSQBUITWSLQITKSXCLLWOFSVOQFKILJXDXFJILLTGOFHXBZEAQQDKIEZYXJJJDQVDVITLXOALMFQJQFFLTWTBFXCJPIAWQZUKYYECDUVZOVYWEWIZIFYQUDGHPLVUPOIBHYSSNNALTXMPCOKVUGWTVWXQHCCUECQSGNUOKASFNNMJAVDVINHHKKQNBFHWNLMMKNCHJGBQZXYQNDEIDWIORIIPGCOOANURPRNLFMQHXFLDUXHCQEDGTUFIZRLQLGVVDKMNXJQJOYWEGFUOYUBLPEOGZFHRZOYVGDNNQRLFSIMRWWZEQDWISILUXDYPQMPNHZEIFKZRAHSOXVKOTBICLAMOFPMOHDWGFZNMAMYEBRPT]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.023 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.653 - pid=71914: 1000 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.653 - pid=71914: Data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
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.653 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.365 - pid=71914: 213 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.365 - pid=71914: Data: [FTBRVOCRNYSBMSVOXGXMXCQHPLDNCKSTGUQJYDSJOZVERBVWNZRUZXEMUGAOPPZCPJLWDPYPXIDRCNDUQNGSURYNTAGNYLKRABZATLXBXTBRQQRYZXDFNRQNMZMLQNHWASNEQUBYUNNNZPNERAHUQSVVCTRNANYRYXPLMMQUJXOSYSDFTUSOFRQRQNLFQBJTEBAGXKNEREVDPSDCZKPRV]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.365 - pid=71914: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.665 - pid=71914: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.665 - pid=71914: Napping 0.628 seconds
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.666 - pid=71914: Woke up 0.628 seconds later
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.666 - pid=71914: Interrupted by signal 15 (SIGTERM)
```

Terminal 2: `fifo-wrt-41; sleep 3; fifo-wrt-41; kill 71914`

Note that the reader was started and hung for about a minute while I futzed around typing the command.  The PID was known from the logging output.

```
$ fifo-wrt-41; sleep 3; fifo-wrt-41; kill 71914
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.329 - pid=71927: Open FIFO './test-fifo' for writing
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.330 - pid=71927: FIFO './test-fifo' opened for writing
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.330 - pid=71927: Napping 0.583 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.915 - pid=71927: Woke up 0.583 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.915 - pid=71927: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.915 - pid=71927: 893 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.915 - pid=71927: Data: [BRIJVUSAANMQOOEWDHXWQCQRVEZLVIPMSDSXHYVDTAGLXPPCUMAZMQLNYHWMWHRZRWHJWXOZYEMUCZXLYFDEFUBSPVICPYVMFWXMZIVZLKFWLFAJWTDBQDWZPEWHXKFXSFJJNUDRZGQQBZMFAQDBYCIUSKPQHQDIDRKIEHNELCSAVHPLYXXLALRJNNVNIVJZWVVPSISUEGTGIISUQZJYVHZLKSMIWTHPOWZJCMMDHMVCCQZPXXRTZOYVEJUIOCYBMRBPBVJYBFZNMZIJDUTVISHLXAGRYOGRYKKOHVONMHTOUSBNBJEYENWADHXYNNCIYEKGXGPPUYRLTNAZROBHWKLDMXHILZXVKRPKUIZXQOOTTKVRMZNDSBRYXGWRZBSQPRPXZSVERASKOLMQQGQFCAXCQMKEHVSRGVFROCQLCLZGNLDLSLQOSKMKWPLJUNCZNTPNXNLIABVBGGTNWGAKTNXZHVHMQAXXKKQWMATQGHIMQCWGGSXGSZDPMJOZMFUJGHPFQHGJTWICLHNKGQGDDZVYGLOBXKUPDXJSEILVVRHNCHKWNKGQMOHCIKXDMQNMSCNPZIXKWEUVOZZCCVCQMFGMUFJJNGSNUCBPDPREEJOCVRUHEILCASMATNJKLDHZWAIJMRBORJLWDUGBTAWKETBNFBZNYJZDKYAOQLERLGWMCNOGWLCYJAFIFCIOMFZEPVRPDAQOGFUAVQOAXPMRBDHBUXSEFRJWSWCEBDFISPGIZOUENNRIEEPBCULDCDMUOSBDQFJYJSAMXZNPZHEEMOLLMAUJDUXGMISSHVWPPFGBJTLDVZMKNYISUXMRQLCTPBPIXATAJFNOJSSAJMSUOQDFGFYBVONMTYQBEWLHGSOVCTWKPWMGAELQGTCZE]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:13.915 - pid=71927: Napping 0.393 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.309 - pid=71927: Woke up 0.393 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.309 - pid=71927: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.309 - pid=71927: 496 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.309 - pid=71927: Data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
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.309 - pid=71927: Napping 0.621 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.934 - pid=71927: Woke up 0.621 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:14.935 - pid=71927: Completed
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.094 - pid=71929: Open FIFO './test-fifo' for writing
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.095 - pid=71929: FIFO './test-fifo' opened for writing
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.095 - pid=71929: Napping 0.429 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.524 - pid=71929: Woke up 0.429 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.524 - pid=71929: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.524 - pid=71929: 351 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.524 - pid=71929: Data: [OORFJGIYUKOWERSICRKHRQRSRDOYRWDLBQCGPPUPFMUTEDHLAJINRWUBYDCFLTDGIAXNPPDQDRCQPVZLEGNJSONSJUTXYEAQDMUXDYFKBUQDNWFCJNXGSLCJVJOCPCHKOERUOJAJUINWTBYOYVAKFOMJPBDCSCMDNVKKRRPJUJKCTCGVGGHIUXVXGAKQFCKVQIUXRNDMUEARVZWRXNOOLYPJHYCBVBMMJEDBKSLGEQFHXVZAUTCMDUFWWHKZNJWVBUCJDJJPWIFMWONIRVPQFTTVZWMVNXCLJOWUFZKUACZAPBJXAEGRJARZALSLWLEXUFEPMNIUTFISQUZNEXKLVCNZNUGVMWM]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:18.524 - pid=71929: Napping 0.495 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.023 - pid=71929: Woke up 0.495 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.023 - pid=71929: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.023 - pid=71929: 465 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.023 - pid=71929: Data: [DYZJOTBGVECGSGBNYNTCVPUSTQGIQQSYTMXWZOQLBUQMGFPILPRIRGTOZFKNHERVCXLFDPLDOKRUCNPNTMCKJXLBGHRIBHKUEKLUGSQBUITWSLQITKSXCLLWOFSVOQFKILJXDXFJILLTGOFHXBZEAQQDKIEZYXJJJDQVDVITLXOALMFQJQFFLTWTBFXCJPIAWQZUKYYECDUVZOVYWEWIZIFYQUDGHPLVUPOIBHYSSNNALTXMPCOKVUGWTVWXQHCCUECQSGNUOKASFNNMJAVDVINHHKKQNBFHWNLMMKNCHJGBQZXYQNDEIDWIORIIPGCOOANURPRNLFMQHXFLDUXHCQEDGTUFIZRLQLGVVDKMNXJQJOYWEGFUOYUBLPEOGZFHRZOYVGDNNQRLFSIMRWWZEQDWISILUXDYPQMPNHZEIFKZRAHSOXVKOTBICLAMOFPMOHDWGFZNMAMYEBRPT]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.023 - pid=71929: Napping 0.626 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.653 - pid=71929: Woke up 0.626 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.653 - pid=71929: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.653 - pid=71929: 1000 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.653 - pid=71929: Data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
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:19.653 - pid=71929: Napping 0.707 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.365 - pid=71929: Woke up 0.707 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.365 - pid=71929: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.365 - pid=71929: 213 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.365 - pid=71929: Data: [FTBRVOCRNYSBMSVOXGXMXCQHPLDNCKSTGUQJYDSJOZVERBVWNZRUZXEMUGAOPPZCPJLWDPYPXIDRCNDUQNGSURYNTAGNYLKRABZATLXBXTBRQQRYZXDFNRQNMZMLQNHWASNEQUBYUNNNZPNERAHUQSVVCTRNANYRYXPLMMQUJXOSYSDFTUSOFRQRQNLFQBJTEBAGXKNEREVDPSDCZKPRV]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.365 - pid=71929: Napping 0.296 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.665 - pid=71929: Woke up 0.296 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:44:20.665 - pid=71929: Completed
$
```

#### Example 2 — Reader reopens file on EOF

Terminal 1: `fifo-rdr-41 -r`

```
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:10.754 - pid=72086: Open FIFO './test-fifo' for reading
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:29.581 - pid=72086: FIFO './test-fifo' opened for reading
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:29.581 - pid=72086: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.131 - pid=72086: 773 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.131 - pid=72086: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.131 - pid=72086: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.430 - pid=72086: 496 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.430 - pid=72086: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.430 - pid=72086: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.907 - pid=72086: 952 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.907 - pid=72086: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.907 - pid=72086: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:31.271 - pid=72086: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:31.271 - pid=72086: Close FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:31.271 - pid=72086: Open FIFO './test-fifo' for reading
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.293 - pid=72086: FIFO './test-fifo' opened for reading
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.293 - pid=72086: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.945 - pid=72086: 984 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.945 - pid=72086: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.945 - pid=72086: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.513 - pid=72086: 880 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.513 - pid=72086: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.513 - pid=72086: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.965 - pid=72086: 510 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.965 - pid=72086: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.966 - pid=72086: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.571 - pid=72086: 900 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.571 - pid=72086: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.571 - pid=72086: Read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.883 - pid=72086: 0 bytes read from FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.883 - pid=72086: Close FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.884 - pid=72086: Open FIFO './test-fifo' for reading
fifo-rdr-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.885 - pid=72086: Interrupted by signal 15 (SIGTERM)
```

Terminal 2: `fifo-wrt-41; sleep 3; fifo-wrt-41; kill 72086`

```
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:29.580 - pid=72090: Open FIFO './test-fifo' for writing
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:29.581 - pid=72090: FIFO './test-fifo' opened for writing
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:29.581 - pid=72090: Napping 0.550 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.131 - pid=72090: Woke up 0.550 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.131 - pid=72090: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.131 - pid=72090: 773 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.131 - pid=72090: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.131 - pid=72090: Napping 0.294 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.429 - pid=72090: Woke up 0.294 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.430 - pid=72090: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.430 - pid=72090: 496 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.430 - pid=72090: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.430 - pid=72090: Napping 0.473 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.907 - pid=72090: Woke up 0.473 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.907 - pid=72090: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.907 - pid=72090: 952 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.907 - pid=72090: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:30.907 - pid=72090: Napping 0.361 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:31.270 - pid=72090: Woke up 0.361 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:31.271 - pid=72090: Completed
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.293 - pid=72093: Open FIFO './test-fifo' for writing
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.293 - pid=72093: FIFO './test-fifo' opened for writing
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.293 - pid=72093: Napping 0.651 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.945 - pid=72093: Woke up 0.651 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.945 - pid=72093: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.945 - pid=72093: 984 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.945 - pid=72093: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:34.945 - pid=72093: Napping 0.568 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.513 - pid=72093: Woke up 0.568 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.513 - pid=72093: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.513 - pid=72093: 880 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.513 - pid=72093: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.513 - pid=72093: Napping 0.451 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.965 - pid=72093: Woke up 0.451 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.965 - pid=72093: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.965 - pid=72093: 510 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.965 - pid=72093: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:35.965 - pid=72093: Napping 0.602 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.571 - pid=72093: Woke up 0.602 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.571 - pid=72093: Write to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.571 - pid=72093: 900 bytes written to FIFO './test-fifo'
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.571 - pid=72093: Data: […omitted for lack of space…]
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.571 - pid=72093: Napping 0.309 seconds
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.883 - pid=72093: Woke up 0.309 seconds later
fifo-wrt-41: 2022-12-31 21:49:36.883 - pid=72093: Completed
```

Comment: (I can't seem to find a way to DM you so I'll write it here)
I am actually trying to understand deeply your explanations and the source codes you sent me, and just realized how helpful you are, everything is clear and precise. Your work is amazing, I would love to spend hours talking with you about programming ahah but I'm just a newbie trying to get to the point I can program serious things. Thanks again, I'll keep you updated !

Comment: See my profile — but please include 'Stack Overflow' or 'SO' in the title and a reference to this question (URL or its title or the question number) in the message.

Comment: Alright, why not ! Thanks man